# Video is not drawn on canvas when autoplay is false on Chromium

Tags: javascript, firefox, html5-canvas, html5-video, chromium

The following code works fine on Firefox whether `autoplay` is true or false but not on Chromium. How can I fix it?

**EDIT 1:** I found out that I can begin with `autoplay = true` and then in `onloadeddata` pause the video with `video.pause()`.

**EDIT 2:** Another interesting thing was found. You can set `video.currentTime` to, for example 5, to capture the 5th second and if the duration of your video is less than, again for example 5s, the last frame will be drawn on the canvas. And then you can set it back to zero in`onloadeddata` event. It is good because in most cases the first seconds are black.

```js
let inputFile = document.getElementById("files");
let container = document.getElementById("container");
inputFile.addEventListener("change", inputFileEventHandler);

function inputFileEventHandler() {
  for (const file of inputFile.files) {
    let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.style.border = "1px solid gray";
    canvas.style.padding = "16px";

    let video = document.createElement("video");
    video.style.width = "250px";
    video.style.height = "auto";
    video.style.border = "1px solid gray";
    video.style.padding = "16px";
    video.autoplay = false;
    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);

    container.append(video);
    container.append(canvas);

    video.onloadeddata = () => {
      canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple>
    <div id="container"></div>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [The loadeddata event is fired when the frame at the current playback position of the media has finished loading; often the first frame.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/loadeddata_event) I guess that it doesn't load first frame in chrome, also - *Note: This event will not fire in mobile/tablet devices if data-saver is on in browser settings.*

Comment: Any workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what is the problem

Seems like `preload: auto` helps, but I'm not sure

Handling multiple events at once makes it work, but not always

```js
let inputFile = document.getElementById("files");
let container = document.getElementById("container");
inputFile.addEventListener("change", inputFileEventHandler);

const events = `abort
canplay
canplaythrough
durationchange
loadeddata
suspend`.split('\n')

function inputFileEventHandler() {

  for (const file of inputFile.files) {
    const video = document.createElement("video");
    video.style.width = "250px";
    video.style.height = "auto";
    video.style.border = "1px solid gray";
    video.style.padding = "16px";
    video.autoplay = false;
    video.preload = 'auto';
    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    container.append(video);

    for (const event of events) {
      const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      canvas.style.border = "1px solid gray";
      canvas.style.padding = "16px";
      container.append(canvas);


      video.addEventListener(event, () => {
        console.log(event)
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
        ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
        ctx.font = "24px serif";
        ctx.fillText(event, 10, 50);
      })
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't know your solution works or not, but I like the way you attached the events to the element :-)

Comment: In spite of what mentioned [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_preload.asp) - the preload attribute is ignored if autoplay is present - your solution works.

Comment: Sorry but now it does not work on Firefox :-D

Comment: Just using preload attribute without autoplay works both on Firefox and Chromium, but currentTime won't work on Firefox with this way.